# Are there hotkeys for non-favorite map modes?

Tags: keyboard, europa-universalis-iv

Other than <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> for favorites, are there keyboard shortcuts for every map mode in EU4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, sorry. The keys are pretty much taken up by other stuff. For more details  check [the full list on the Wiki](http://www.eu4wiki.com/Controls)